# Unable pass data from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to send data from Teachers Fragment to OneTeacher Fragment. I found the following code from the internet. But it gives an output as "Null" when I clicked an item of the Listbox.

Please be kind enough to give a solution for this.
*(My question is why I can't send the data from Teachers Fragment to One Teacher Fragment by using following code).*

**Teachers Fragment**

```
try {
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tName);

               String teachernamefrom = myTextView.getText().toString();

               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), teachernamefrom, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               //this toast works properly

               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("key1",teachernamefrom);

               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OneTeacherFragment())
                        .addToBackStack("tag")
                        .commit();

               Fragment nextFrag = new OneTeacherFragment();
               nextFrag.setArguments(bundle);

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**OneTeacherFragment:**

```
        teacherName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_name);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null){
            String key = bundle.getString("key1");
            teacherName.setText(key);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763977/how-do-i-pass-a-custom-object-to-a-list-in-a-different-fragment/54764097 see this.

Comment: **Fragment nextFrag = new OneTeacherFragment();
               nextFrag.setArguments(bundle);**       
         
**getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag)
                        .addToBackStack("tag")
                        .commit();**
change your code like above code:

Comment: Do efforts to do R&D before posting any questions

Answer (score 0):

change code in `onItemClick`

You are passing new object `OneTeacherFragment()` while replacing `Fragment`, You 
 shoud pass `nextFrag`

```
// create OneTeacherFragment
Fragment nextFrag = new OneTeacherFragment();
// set bundle arguments
nextFrag.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, 
android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag) // pass created nextFrag
                    .addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I already accepted the answer. But my reputation is not enough. So it doesn't affect the publicly displayed post score. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have set the arguments and make transactions on that instance rather than the current approach

```
// Create an instance of the fragment
Fragment nextFrag = new OneTeacherFragment();

// Create an instance of a bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
// Pass data to the bundle
bundle.putString("key1",teachernamefrom);
// Set the arguments
nextFrag.setArguments(bundle);

// Perform the fragment transaction with the created instance
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag)
.addToBackStack("tag")
.commit();
```